# Cloudformation apigateway cache setup for proxy resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

Can someone please provide advice on how to specify a cache policy with a [greedy path sub-resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html) ('{proxy+}') in a cloudformation template.

I have setup a REST API using apigateway via CloudFormation. The gateway is configured with a generalised [cache policy on the stage deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-stage-methodsetting.html#cfn-apigateway-stage-methodsetting-httpmethod). However, for a particular greedy path sub-resource I am wanting to specify a custom cache policy. I am able to successfully achieve this via the template when the path name is a standard string (e.g. "/~1abcde~1fghijk"), but not for '{proxy+}' as per snippet below.

```
  Stage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      RestApiId: xxxx
      StageName: xxxx
      Description: 'Api stage for deployment'
      DeploymentId: xxxx
      TracingEnabled: True
      CacheClusterEnabled: True
      CacheClusterSize: 0.5
      MethodSettings:
        - ResourcePath: "/~1abcde~1fghijk"
          HttpMethod: "*"
          CacheTtlInSeconds: 0
          CachingEnabled: false
        - ResourcePath: "/~1abcde~1{proxy+}"
          HttpMethod: "*"
          CacheTtlInSeconds: 0
          CachingEnabled: false
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is the problem? The template does not deploy? Any errors?

Comment: No errors, template deploys fine. Problem is that the policy is not taking affect as the resource is still inheriting from stage instead of overriding.

Comment: If you do the same, but using console, does it work as expected? Thus, the question is how to replicate this in CFN?

Comment: Correct. No issues when overriding via console.

Comment: Can you use aws cli [get-stage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-stage.html) to get details when you set it up in console. This should show how `ResourcePath` or other parameters are set when done in console. Usually, this is good indication how to do same in cfn.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for your help, have identified and fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue. With thanks to Marcin's comments.

I am able to override the deployment stage policies when specifying the particular HttpMethod. For some reason, contrary to the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-stage-methodsetting.html#cfn-apigateway-stage-methodsetting-httpmethod), using a wildcard "*" for HttpMethod was causing a silent fail. New cloudformation resource template snippet as per below:

```
    - ResourcePath: "/~1abcde~1{proxy+}"
      HttpMethod: GET
      CacheTtlInSeconds: 0
      CachingEnabled: false
```